# How do I merge data without duplicating the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-cleaning

Let's say I have multiple data frames df1,df2,df3 (in reality,I have about 11 data frames). These are converted to data frames from excel worksheets.

for example purpose:

```
     DateTime  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
       ----------------
   jan  | 20 | 30 | 40 |
   Feb  | NaN | NaN| NaN |
   Mar  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
   Apr  | NaN |NaN | NaN |


        | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
       ----------------
   jan  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
   Feb  | 20 | 30 | 40 |
   Mar  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
   Apr  | NaN |NaN | NaN |
       | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
       ----------------
   jan  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
   Feb  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
   Mar  | 10 | 20 | 80 |
   Apr  | NaN |NaN | NaN |
```

I would like the output to be

```
Out= DateTime   | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
       ----------------
   jan  | 20 | 30 | 40 |
   Feb  | 20 | 30 | 0 |
   Mar  | 10 | 20 | 80 |
   Apr  | NaN |NaN | NaN |
```

Say, there are multiple columns but same names in all, and multiple rows but the date column has the same number of rows and names in all the spreadsheets. I tried to join, merge and concatenate but they either overwrite the values, or add extra rows or columns. In the end, I would like the output to have the same number of rows and columns.

I am new to python, so trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`, solution working with column `date`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('date', sort=False).sum(min_count=1)
```

If working with DatetimeIndex:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum(min_count=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
     Col1  Col2  Col3
jan  20.0  30.0  40.0
Feb  20.0  30.0  40.0
Mar  10.0  20.0  80.0
Apr   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I have a date column and that column is not showing up. Also, the "NaN" values are now filled as 0. I want them to be "NaN".

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar - answer was edited.

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar which NaN? there is none in the question. Please provide a correct/complete example

Comment: None values. no values. I have edites

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar - you forget for column `date`

Comment: When I tried this df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum(min_count=1), the Date time column is omitted.

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar - need first solution `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('date', sort=False).sum(min_count=1)`

Comment: It's throwing an error: "level name Date is not the name of the index"

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar - there is no parameter `level` in `.groupby('date', sort=False)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. All the Empty values are showing up as "0" instead of being empty.

Comment: How can I retain the empty values being empty instead of showing up as "0"

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar - for me working well, is not possible in one DataFrame is emty cell and same cell in another is `0` ? then ouput is `0`

Answer (score 0):

As of the provided examples in the question, you can also perform a simple `sum`. The operation will align automatically on the index/columns.

example input (with added NaN):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 0, 0], 'Col2': [30, 0, 0], 'Col3': [40, 0, 0]},
                   index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0, 20, 0], 'Col2': [0, 30, 0], 'Col3': [0, 40, np.nan]},
                   index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0, 0, 10], 'Col2': [0, 0, 20], 'Col3': [0, 0, 80]},
                   index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
```

code:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_out = sum(dfs)
```

output:

```
     Col1  Col2  Col3
Jan    20    30  40.0
Feb    20    30  40.0
Mar    10    20   NaN
```

*NB. if you have other columns, please define the behavior*

Comment: TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: ya, not sure if need op lost `80` if nan in another position, I guess not.

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar this is why you should provide a reproducible example as dataframe constructor, not just text tables ;)

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you